# Is it possible to consume a WCFservice in a .net app and disable validation of an <xs:sequence> elements?

Tags: .net, wcf, xsd-validation

I have a problem where I'm consuming a 3rd-party WCF service, but the 3rd party keeps changing the order of the elements within an <xs:sequence>.  This causes my .net app to bomb when deserializing the incoming xml response from the 3rd party WCF.

*

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
> message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
> http://blahblah.com/webservices/GetResult. The InnerException message
> was 'Error in line 1 position 2243. 'Element' 'SysRef' from namespace
> 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/' is not expected. Expecting
> element 'StateInf'.
> *

obviously the sequence should always be in the order specified in the original XSD, but the 3rd party shenanigans is beyond my control.

I suspect it's something to do with datacontract.org, but I would really like to switch the pre-validation off once in production.

Is that possible?

In reference.vb, the class generated for this part of the response has this DataContractAttribute attribute:

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), 
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0"), 
  System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name:="DetailsResponse", [Namespace]:="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/"),  
System.SerializableAttribute()>  _
Partial Public Class DetailsResponse
```

Anybody had experience of this?

Comment: This is a server-side problem. It is difficult for us to solve it on the client-side. I suggest you contact the WCF service provider.

Comment: Ding Peng Difficult or impossible?  I find it hard to believe that we can't deserialize some xml just because of the <xs:sequence> rules.  To me it should be analogous to using an XMLReader instead of an XMLValidatingReader...

Comment: It is impossible. You need to contact the WCF service provider.